# Navigation/dropdown closes when carousel slide changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 2.3.2 and just introduced [Infinity slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/infinityslider-jquery-slider-css3-animations/7103544)

When I'm using the dropdown nav and the slider changes slide, the dropdown nav disappears and I have to open it again (but quickly before the next transition). This is probably because the slider is active the "active state" of the menu gets overridden.

Is there a way to force the bootstrap menu to stay open or make it take priority over the Infinity slider (run the slider in the background, the default bootstrap slider/carousel does this).

If anyone has experienced the same or may know a way around it would be appreciated muchly!

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/133453 - here is an example of the problem. Open the menu in the top right and leave it open until slide changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out - in Bootstrap.js I commented out the line (under dropdown api-standard dropdown elements:

```
.on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
```